# How do inline functions increase memory cache miss and why is it bad compared to the alternative?

Tags: c++, function, caching, inline

From https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf,

> Inlining might cause an inner loop to span across multiple lines of
>   the memory cache, and that might cause thrashing of the memory-cache.

Let us consider the alternative, the function is not inlined. Then also memory cache miss will occur, after the function returns the control to the loop. Additionally, registers will need to be pushed and popped from the stack.

Considering the above facts, inline version will be faster[ruling out page fault due to bloated executable size, and other factors] even with memory cache miss than non-inline version.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, your analysis is correct. I can provide a counter-example, however: If your inner loop calls the same function multiple times and that function is inlined, the resulting code might occupy more cache lines than the non-inlined version.

Of course, it will vary in varying scenarios.

Comment: I think, you are talking about instruction cache line. The question was about memory cache line. About instruction cache miss, Loop unrolling is one scenario, where what you said would hold true, could you provide example of any other scenario that would happen. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but in modern microprocessors, the distinction between instruction and data cache goes away after L1. In L2 and beyond, instructions and data are sharing the same capacity.